# In Rails Forms, how to key nested association by association's primary key instead of by index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

With Rails (4.2) forms, how can I construct a form such that the request's payload represents the nested association as a hash, which is key'd by the association's primary key?

I have a nested form as demonstrated in [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for). If you scroll down you will see the following example:

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  ...
  <%= person_form.fields_for :projects do |project_fields| %>
    Project #<%= project_fields.index %>
    ...
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

When the form makes an HTTP PATCH request the payload my endpoint receives is shaped as such:

```
"person"=>{"project_attributes"=>{"0"=>{...}, "1"=>{...}, "2"=>{...}...}}
```

Instead of the keys of `project_attributes` representing the numerically ordered index, I want the key to be the primary key, `id`, of the project.

EDIT:

The reason why I want the key to be the primary key of the project is so that in my controller I can more easily update the projects as follows:

```
# Option 1
Project.update(params[:project_attributes].keys, params[:project_attributes].values)

# Option 2
params[:project_attributes].keys.each do |project_id|
  Project.update(project_id, params[:project_attributes][project_id])
end
```

Comment: "I want the key to be the primary key, id, of the project" Could you explain why you're wanting this, so we can understand what the end goal is?

Comment: @DanielWestendorf sure thing. I will update the question.

Comment: Are you using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`? If so, `Person.update(params.permit!)` would update the associated project's attributes for you automatically. (don't use `params.permit!` in production, configure `strong_parameters` correctly).

Comment: @DanielWestendorf thank you for your suggestion. What does `params` look like exactly? would it look like, `params = { id: 1, project_attributes: [{id: 2...}, {id: 5...}] } ?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to do this, and you won't need to worry about the parameters and how they're passed.

For a reference of how `accepts_nested_attributes_for` should be used,  [follow this guide](https://www.fococoder.com/articles/37).

Comment: Thank you! Person.update(person_id, params[:project_attributes]) worked exactly how I wanted it to.